# How to make a CircularFifoQueue threadsafe?

Tags: java, spring, queue

I'd like to use a `CircularFifoQueue` with spring `ExecutorService`.

The following does not compile, because `CircularFifoQueue` is not of type `BlockingQueue`. But it shows what I'm trying to achieve:

```
int threads = 10;
int queueSize = 500;
new java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor(threads, threads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 
                new CircularFifoQueue(queueSize));
```

With:

```
package org.apache.commons.collections4.queue;

public class CircularFifoQueue<E> extends AbstractCollection<E>
       implements Queue<E>, BoundedCollection<E>, Serializable
```

Question: does the code above provide thread safety (as `CircularFifoQueue` itself is not threadsafe)?
If not, how can I make it threadsafe?

Comment: Where does CircularFifoQueue come from?

Comment: Is CircularFifoQueue a blocking queue?

Comment: Added package info above. It is *not* a BlockingQueue (which would be threadsafe by design).

Comment: This code won't compile, because the queue has to be a BockingQueue, given that ThreadPoolExecutor is the one in the JDK?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi oh ok, you're right. So how could I then make use of a circular queue with `TaskExecutor`?

Answer (score 4):

You can synchronize using commons-collections [QueueUtils.synchronizedQueue](https://github.com/apache/commons-collections/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/collections4/QueueUtils.java)

`Queue queue = QueueUtils.synchronizedQueue(new CircularFifoQueue());`

But according to javadoc it needs additional synchronization for serial access:

> In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the
>       backing queue is accomplished through the returned queue.
>
> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned queue
>       when iterating over it:
>
> ```
> Queue queue = QueueUtils.synchronizedQueue(new CircularFifoQueue());
> ...
> synchronized(queue) {
>     Iterator i = queue.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>     while (i.hasNext())
>         foo(i.next());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: Note: this method available only since version 4.2 of commons-collections.

Comment: if you need to use `synchronized` anyway then why bother to wrap by `QueueUtils.synchronizedQueue` at all?

Comment: synchronized block is required only for serial access (iterating over queue) what is not common usage of queue. Add/poll/peek become synchronized in QueueUtils.synchronizedQueue.

Answer (score 2):

Work queues are meant to be blocking, and hence you would need to add a `decorator` to make that `CircularFifoQueue` a `BLockingQueue`.

```
class BlockingCircularFifoQueue<E> implements BlockingQueue<E>{
  private CircularFifoQueue<E> backingCollection;
  ...
}
```

And delegate to the backing collection when needed.
You would need to get [Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) and [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) right of course.

Comment: is extending CircularFifoQueue a bad design ?

Comment: @Dexter yes it is,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance

Comment: I think "is a relationship" holds true here. Anyway, thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to practically write your own queue implementation.
Since CircularFifoQueue uses an underlying array to hold the elements, I would take help of the ArrayBlockingQueue data structure in java.util.concurrent package as a starting point.

Example :

```
class ThreadSafeCircularFifoQueue<T> extends CircularFifoQueue<T> implements BlockingQueue<T> {

    /** Main lock guarding all access */
    final ReentrantLock lock;

    /** Condition for waiting takes */
    private final Condition notEmpty;

    /** Condition for waiting puts */
    private final Condition notFull;

    @Override
    public int size() {

        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            return super.size();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    //and so forth
}
```